# String cut of leading zeros

Tags: android

I have a lot of pictures which have a numeric ending like page_001, page_002 ... page_148. Now I'm not sure how to implement them in my ViewPager which uses Universal image Loader.

Here is my `instantiateItem` Method, right now i have a fix image for testing purposes. How can i format the FileName ending so i can use the Position for indicating which image should be loaded? or any other way?

001 -> 1
002 -> 2
..
148 -> 148

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageLoader.displayImage(String.format("%s%s/%s_Page_001.jpg", mProtocolPathName, mFilDir, mFilDir), imageView, options);
    container.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3I used mFileNumber for the file number but this should give you an idea how to do it.

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageLoader.displayImage(String.format("%s%s/%s_Page_%03d.jpg", mProtocolPathName, mFilDir, mFilDir, mFileNumber), imageView, options);
    container.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: worked thanks!. Looks like this now
 imageLoader.displayImage(String.format("%s%s/%s_Page_%03d.jpg", mProtocolPathName, mFilDir, mFilDir,position+1), imageView, options);

Could you maybe explain whats happening with the %3d ?

Comment: it means you want the total length of the string to be 3 characters and you want it padded with a 0. The first character "0" is the padding character and the second "3" is the total length.

Comment: what would happen if the ending of the file is  page_10000 ? Would this cut anything of?

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageLoader.displayImage(String.format("%s%s/%s_Page_%03d.jpg", mProtocolPathName, mFilDir, mFilDir, position), imageView, options);
    container.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")` to cut off leading zeros.
or in your case exctract the number from string by `Integer.valueOf(String.split("page_")[1].replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""));`

Comment: Won't this replace *all* zeroes, including those that are desired? What I mean is won't this change something like "4053.jpg" with "453.jpg"?